# Transforming a Graph

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am working on transforming a graph.  The problem I am having is the equation is different than what I am use to and I could use some help understanding how to read the function.  I understand $f(x)=x$.  The x in this function is the independent variable, and the $f(x)$ is the y value or is the dependent variable.  Two coordinates on a graph would be:

$$ \begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 & \text{x} & \text{y} \\ \hline
\text{coordinates} & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
\text{coordinates} & 2 & 2 \\ \hline
\end{array} $$

I put a value in the function for x and then the function spits out a value for y.

The function I am working on looks like there are two y values.  $y=f(1/2x)$.  Are there two ys and no x coordinates?  I also have to transform the a graph by using the reciprocal. Why do I use the reciprocal?  Looking at this equation I would think the graph coordinates would be
$$ \begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 & \text{x} & \text{y} \\ \hline
\text{coordinates} & 1 & 1/2 \\ \hline
\text{coordinates} & 2 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{array} $$

It is the opposite of what I think and I am not sure why.  Here is what the book is telling me to do
$$ \begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 & \text{x} & \text{y} \\ \hline
\text{coordinates} & 1 & 2 \\ \hline
\text{coordinates} & 2 & 4 \\ \hline
\end{array} $$

I am not really sure why the reciprocal is being used and think it probably has to do with how the equation is written.

Comment: you might like to include the original question.

Comment: Your book is telling you to make a table of coordinates to understand the graph? Throw that crap out lol.

Comment: I probably will.  The problem came from Alex.  I am stuck.  Thanks for the humor.